# Do Javascript run times cache/optimize nested object accesses?

Tags: javascript, benchmarking

**Optional Context**:

I am writing a tool that generates code to automatically validate Typescript types, so I am wondering whether my generated code is efficient.

Currently, my tool outputs this code:

```js
const newVersion = (p0) =>
  !!p0 &&
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(p0, "a") &&
  !!p0["a"] &&
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(p0["a"], "b") &&
  !!p0["a"]["b"] &&
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(p0["a"]["b"], "c") &&
  typeof p0["a"]["b"]["c"] === "object" &&
  p0["a"]["b"]["c"] !== null &&
  !!p0["a"]["b"] &&
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(p0["a"]["b"], "d") &&
  !!p0["a"]["b"]["d"] &&
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(p0["a"]["b"]["d"], "e") &&
  typeof p0["a"]["b"]["d"]["e"] === "number";
```

to validate this Typescript type

```js
a: { b: { c: {}; d: { e: number } } };
```

**Actual Question**:

If I have the following: `p0["a"]["b"]["c"] === some_value`, and a few lines later I do `p0["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"] === another_value`, will the Javascript engine(s) (where Javascript engines = whatever is in Chrome/Safari/Firefox) remember that I accessed `p0["a"]["b"]["c"]` and use it to make the 2nd access faster.

Because if the above is not the case, then I will change my code generation to output something like this (not exactly the same effect as the above code, but similar):

```js
    const old =  p12 => {
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(p12, "a") || !(p18 => {
      if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(p18, "b") || !(p21 => {
        if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(p21, "c") || !(p22 => {
          return true;
        })(p21.c)) return false;
        if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(p21, "d") || !(p23 => {
          if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(p23, "e") || !(typeof p23.e === "number")) return false;
          return true;
        })(p21.d)) return false;
        return true;
      })(p18.b)) return false;
      return true;
    })(p12.a)) return false;
    return true;
  }
```

As a side note: Is there a speed difference between bracket access and dot style access? I know these things normally don't matter, but I figure since I'm doing automatic code generation I might as well micro-optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Just general suggestion: why not use a loop instead

```js
const data = { a: { b: { c: "C value", d: { e: "number" } } } };
const safeEval = (obj, key) => {
  const keys = key.split("?.");
  let m = obj;
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(m, keys[i])) {
      m = m[keys[i]];
      continue;
    } else {
     m = undefined
      break;
    }
  }
  return m;
};
console.log(safeEval(data, "a?.b?.c"));
```

Comment: I am automatically generating code -- the above was a simple example, but I need to handle a bunch of other cases as well. Boolean expressions are easy to generate, loops are harder.

Comment: if i notice typescript

`(_b = (_a = data === null || data === void 0 ? void 0 : data.a) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.b) === null || _b === void 0 ? void 0 : _b.c["x"]`

Comment: I'm also not doing safe access, I'm doing validation so I need to check that some arbitrary object matches the the schema `a: { b: { c: {}; d: { e: number } } };`. But also there could be more complicated scenarios like `a: { b: { c: {d: number}; d: { e: number } } };` etc.